# How to add newlines to psql queries without submitting the query?

Tags: psql

I enter a multi-line query into psql. Then I need to revise the query. I press up and the previously ran query is now editable. When revising a multi-line query, I am unable to add additional newlines. Both the enter key and the shift+enter keys will re-submit the query instead of adding a newline character.

Without copying the query to an external editor, how do you add newlines to psql queries without re-submitting the query?

Comment: That's what `\edit` is intended for. It will pass the buffer to an external editor automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find that anywhere.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: If that page showed up during my search results, the first paragraph of `/edit` would have convinced me it was unrelated.